# Validate XML with Schematron in PHP 5

Tags: php, xml, xslt, schematron, cda

I have a problem with validating XML with [schematron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schematron).

In my code I load the XML and XSL as DOMDocument objects and I try to transform:

```
$domSche = new DOMDocument();
$domSche->loadXML($message);

$domXSLSche = new DOMDocument();
$domXSLSche->load("CI-SIS_StructurationCommuneCDAr2.xsl");

$xsltsche = new XSLTProcessor();
$xsltsche->importStylesheet($domXSLSche);

$XSLValid = $xsltsche->transformToXml($domSche);
```

But the function returns this error:

> XSLTProcessor::transformToXml(): No stylesheet associated to this
>   object

I don't understand, technically, the importStylesheet associates my XSL to the XML, no?

If someone wants to look at more sources, files are at :

- [$message](http://pastebin.com/zEHnYP2t)
- [CI-SIS_StructurationCommuneCDAr2.xsl](http://pastebin.com/9e19wiHf)

Comment: See similar: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4822914/287948

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Schematron version you make use of does not require XSL 2.0 however the file you have makes use of XSL 2.0 features.

`XSLTProcessor` in PHP supports XSL 1.0 only. Some of the features used in that file are therefore not available and make the import fail.

As the stylesheet could not be imported, the transformation can not run.

---

The error message

> Warning: XSLTProcessor::transformToXml(): No stylesheet associated to this object

means that the stylesheet is missing. Not on disk or in memory, but for the transformation.

That is because it has errors and finally could not compile.

In your case the XSL file you have is of version 2.0 but PHP only supports 1.0 features. Also it makes use of variables that are not set (defined). When I load your example data I get the following errors:

> Warning: XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet(): compilation error: file CI-SIS_StructurationCommuneCDAr2.xsl line 13 element stylesheet

Which is:

```
            version="2.0">
```

and explained by the next warning:

> Warning: XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet(): xsl:version: only 1.0 features are supported

Next is an undefined variable:

> Warning: XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet(): Undefined variable
>
> Warning: XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet(): compilation error: file CI-SIS_StructurationCommuneCDAr2.xsl line 4974 element template

which is

```
    <!--RULE -->
    <xsl:template match="*[cda:templateId/@root = $templateObservationMedia]" priority="1000"
                  mode="M62">
```

which is the `$templateObservationMedia` variable and leads to

> Warning: XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet(): Failed to compile predicate

To get this working you would need at least fix these problems. As using the variable inside the match pattern is not XSLT 1.0 you need to work around that at least. See [Multiple PHP Warnings in XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1711001/367456) for an extended discussion of the variable/match issue.